# Rails Tutorial NoMethodError undefined method `activation_digest=' for #<User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I have been trying to extend the Rails Hartl tutorial. I seem to be running into an issue. On heroku I run into an issue, while on my machine it runs fine.
When I try to create a user, I get this message in the logs.

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `activation_digest=' for  #<User:0x00000003156938>

2018-03-21T01:58:59.786203+00:

00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  activation_token=):"
```

Followed by

```
FATAL -- : [78d926f5-adcf-4bb2-a289-638c82d9f0f5] app/models/user.rb:72:in `create_activation_digest'

[78d926f5-adcf-4bb2-a289-638c82d9f0f5] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

I have looked through both the users model and controller, but cannot find a reason as to why this does not run. They both match the source of Hartl's bitbucket. I have looked through db migrations and they all look correct as well.

My repository is listed here: https://bitbucket.org/Grev0ushede/blog_app/src/master/

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you run `db:migrate` on heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your terminal run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do so on heroku's end. I appreciate it.

Comment: When it works locally but not on heroku this is usually the answer